# Teamcity VCS revision GUID

Tags: teamcity, plasticscm

I am trying to retrieve the VCS revision GUID but I don't know where I can find it. I've searched in the Predefined parameters without success, any idea how can I get this GUID?

I should add that I am using PlasticSCM as VCS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUID is not shown in the predefined variables, but you can get it running:

```
cm find changeset where changesetid=build.vcs.number --format={guid} --nototal
```

Answer (score 0):

The VCS revision included in the build is stored in **build.vcs.number** parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. This gives only a number like 239 but I am looking for the revision GUID.